# Switch won't forward a ping outside LAN despite having a default gateway

Tags: switching

Maybe I'm just tired, but I can't get basic connectivity in my network. I've built this on Packet Tracer for the sake of troubleshooting and I've removed everything but the important elements. Here's the network:

[image: Network]

PC0: 192.168.0.1/24 and a DG of 192.168.0.2

Switch configs:

```
vlan 4
name vlan4

int vlan 4
ip add 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
no shut

int range fa0/1-2
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 4
no shut
exit

ip default-gateway 192.168.0.3
```

R0:

```
! Towards R1
int g0/0/0
ip add 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
no shut

! Towards VLAN 4
int g0/0/1
ip add 192.168.0.3 255.255.255.0
no shut

router rip
network 192.168.0.0
network 10.10.10.0
exit
```

R1:

```
int g0/0
ip add 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.0
no shut

int lo0
ip add 100.100.100.100 255.255.255.255
no shut
exit

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 lo0

router rip
network 10.10.10.0
network 100.100.100.100
default-information originate
```

The switch can ping everything, just as expected. The problem is that the PC can't ping anything outside its VLAN. The switch just drops it. I thought The switch would simply forward it to its default gateway, in this case R0. I'm for sure missing something very basic, but I just don't know what. How can I allow PC0 to ping R1's Lo0?

Comment: The switch default gateway is for the switch VLAN 4 interface, and it has nothing to do with the PC. The PC needs its own default gateway.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the default gateway on the PC to 192.168.0.3 instead of 192.168.0.2.

Switch0 cannot act as default gateway since it is a switch, not a router.

Answer (score 2):

`ip default-gateway` is a *host mode* command. It has no effect in routing traffic through the system -- if it even is routing. You would also never send traffic to 0.2 for it to just hand it on to 0.3; the PC can do that directly.

As the switch appears to only have one network (vlan 4, 192.168.0.0/24), it has nothing to route. Routing requires more than one layer-3 network.